# Multiple data sets in Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-styling

I am trying to categorize tens of thousands of people all over the country.

I know that there are around 60 categories of people, and the distribution is definitely not random. 15k to 20k people fall in one category and there are few categories without any people at all in them.

Finally I do a big list of the following data
[lat/long, categoryId, count] - There are #count number of users belonging to #categoryId in the given lat/long.

I do have thousands of this list and am trying to show them all in Google maps.

I definitely need to visually contrast each category separately so that I can check which category gets along with which other category people. Also I also want to show bigger #count distinctly (like a bigger circle or something if we choose to show all of the data in circles).

Right now it is possible to show everything, but the UI gets totally cluttered and no one is able to make any sense out of the data. Any thoughts on how to visualize this data? and are there any techniques (some javascript plugins that already does that?)

This is a proxy of the real problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a clustering algorithm to the data and clulster the points on the map to make them more readable. We did something similar on this project:

http://roadworksonline.org.uk/

Comment: That helps, and frankly I thought of that and I ended up having way too many overlapping circles that seeing that also was becoming problem.

Comment: Not really sure how you could avoid the circles overlapping to be honest. Maybe provide a way to select which colours/categories to display at any one time to make the data more manageable.

Comment: Yeah I'm negotiating with the business team for that only. If you don't mind, can you please tell which Clustering algorithm you were using? I took the code from a legacy project and it is taking a lot of time to run.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code as I have now moved on from that company. It was a clustering algorithm constructed by our Oracle specialist at the time. I am unsure as to whether she wrote it off her own back or followed another. I suspect she wrote it herself though as she was pretty good.

Comment: It's ok, I will luck it up somewhere. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. There should be a few out there. I would google things like 'spatial data clustering algorithm. I believe the way our Oracle specialist did it was to work out a grid of even sized squares over the map and then decide which points fell inside which grid square and then put the point into a cluster. If the point was on its own in the square it would be displayed as a single feature as you can see on the web site I posted. As you zoom on the map the size of the grid squares was smaller to allow higher levels of detail.detail.

Comment: The clustering was performed in the database on a refresh and stored in cluster tables which held the clusters and points for each zoom level. Does that make sense? If not I can provide more detail via pm or something.